# Add Menubar to existing MainWindow Class

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have a working app that I would like to add a menubar to. I have tried several methods shown in other questions here on Stackoverflow and have not found a working solution.

I've tried setting up the MenuBar as its own class, adding the menubar code to the MainWindow class, defining the menubar as a function and calling it as a Mainwindow method. All ideas gained from other posts.

```
# This class defines the Main Window of my working app

class MainWindow(Frame,Menu):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.menubar=MenuBar(self)
        self.openButton = Button(self, text="Open", command=self.opencallback)
        self.openButton.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.fileEntry = Entry(self)
        self.fileEntry.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.fileName = None
        self.AnalyzeButton = Button(self, text="Analyze", command=self.analyzeCallback)
        self.AnalyzeButton.pack(side=LEFT)      
        self.QuitButton = Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.closeAll)
        self.QuitButton.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

```
# This class defines how I would like the Menu to look when it appears in the Main application window 

class MenuBar(Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Menu.__init__(self, parent)
        fileMenu = Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        toolMenu = Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="Tools", menu=toolMenu)
        toolMenu.add_command(label="Extract Instructions", command=None)
```

I would like the menubar to appear at the top of the MainWindow with two drop downs File and Tools. So far I have been able to generate the MainWindow by itself (no menu) and the Menu by itself (blank tk window with nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks fine to me except you have not told the root window about the menu. See my example, the last line in `__init__()`:

```
from tkinter import *   # For Ptyhon 2.7 use Tkinter instead

class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.geometry('300x200')
        self.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
        self.menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menubar)   # Tell root about the menu

    def menu_callback_stop(self):
        print('Exit')

    def menu_callback_extract(self):
        print('Extract Instructions')

class MenuBar(Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Menu.__init__(self, parent)
        fileMenu = Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=parent.menu_callback_stop)
        toolMenu = Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="Tools", menu=toolMenu)
        toolMenu.add_command(label="Extract Instructions",
                             command=parent.menu_callback_extract)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app =  MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I added callbacks to the `MainWindow` instance.